# Why does mysql treat "<" like it was "<="?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

I've tried the following command:

```
SELECT * FROM `mi_schedule` WHERE `day`<=(DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL 7 DAY)) AND `day`>=NOW()
```

Got 8 rows. Then I changed the `<=` to `<`, and nothing changed, still 8 rows.

So I changed the interval from `7` to `6`:

```
SELECT * FROM `mi_schedule` WHERE `day`<(DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL 6 DAY)) AND `day`>=NOW()
```

and I got one less row from the results (7 total), as expected.

I switched back from `<` to `<=`, and again nothing changed.

I.e. apparently the `<` is considered to be a `<=` instead.

Is that intentional? According to [the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_less-than), it shouldn't.

PS: `day` is a `DATE` type.

(using version `5.5.29`, engine InnoDB)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you working with datetimes?

Notice that If I ran it now I'd get for instance:

```
August, 28 2014 13:57:36+0000
```

Which means that if my dates are at midnight I'd get the same with `<` and `<=`

You should probably cast this into DATE if you are to work with dates

Comment: yeah, `DATE(NOW())` did the trick, I somehow assumed there was something automatic when there wasn't. Thanks.

Comment: `DATE(NOW())` or `CURRENT_DATE`